# Some questions about the C++ boost graph library

Tags: c++, boost, graph

So I'm posting this because I'm currently working on an algorithm project and might gonna use the boost library for building a graph from an input text file. So I have noticed that there is a descriptor for the vertex in a graph, but since I have a very large graph to be built, do I need to allocate a descriptor for every vertex in that graph? If I don't, can I traverse the whole graph after it's been built?

I'm a newbie to the boost library and this is a little emergent so if anybody can explain this I will be very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph)?

Answer (score 3):

A vertex descriptor describes a vertex (in cheap, graph model independent way).

A graph model describes a graph.

### Iterators

When you want to traverse a graph, you traverse the graph, using the iterators:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;
typedef Graph::vertex_iterator Vit;

Vit begin, end;
boost::tie(begin, end) = vertices(g);
```

Dereferencing a valid iterator gives you the descriptor (same thing goes for edge iterators).

Simple demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0c854790b4d7311)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;
    typedef Graph::vertex_iterator Vit;
    Graph g(10);

    add_edge(2,5,g);
    add_edge(5,3,g);
    add_edge(3,8,g);

    Vit begin, end;
    boost::tie(begin, end) = vertices(g);

    for (Vit it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        unsigned edges = out_degree(*it, g);
        if (edges)
            std::cout << "vertex #" << *it << " has " << edges << " outgoing edge(s)\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
vertex #2 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex #3 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex #5 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
```

### Graph Model With Node-Based Vertex Containers

Not all graph have integral vertex descriptors, so adding edges becomes more complicated, and printing them doesn't look so "friendly"

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5efb5fa8983e8d79)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS/*, boost::undirectedS*/> Graph;
    typedef Graph::vertex_iterator Vit;
    Graph g(10);

    Vit begin, end;
    boost::tie(begin, end) = vertices(g);

    {
        std::vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> vindex(begin, end);
        add_edge(vindex[2], vindex[5], g);
        add_edge(vindex[5], vindex[3], g);
        add_edge(vindex[3], vindex[8], g);
    }

    for (Vit it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        unsigned edges = out_degree(*it, g);
        if (edges)
            std::cout << "vertex #" << *it << " has " << edges << " outgoing edge(s)\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
vertex #0x994d00 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex #0x994d70 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex #0x994e50 has 1 outgoing edge(s)
```

### Properties

In such cases, consider adding a [property bundle](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html).

This way, arbitrary application-specific information can be attached to model vertices (or edges, or graphs).

> The main downside, in my opinion, of this is that there's no natural indexing for the properties, so looking up a graph entity by its (bundled) property could get bad performance (linear search) unless you keep an extra index outside of the graph manually.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07666c58cca3923a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct VertexProperties {
    std::string name;
    VertexProperties(std::string name) : name(name) {}
};

int main () {
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, VertexProperties> Graph;
    typedef Graph::vertex_iterator Vit;
    Graph g;

    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("zero"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("one"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("two"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("three"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("four"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("five"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("six"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("seven"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("eight"), g);
    add_vertex(VertexProperties ("nine"), g);

    Vit begin, end;
    boost::tie(begin, end) = vertices(g);

    {
        std::vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> vindex(begin, end);

        add_edge(vindex[2], vindex[5], g);
        add_edge(vindex[5], vindex[3], g);
        add_edge(vindex[3], vindex[8], g);
    }

    for (Vit it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        unsigned edges = out_degree(*it, g);
        if (edges)
            std::cout << "vertex '" << g[*it].name << "' has " << edges << " outgoing edge(s)\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
vertex 'two' has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex 'three' has 1 outgoing edge(s)
vertex 'five' has 1 outgoing edge(s)
```

Comment: I have been going nuts trying to understand BGL for the last few days!  Thank you for this terrific neat little answer.