# How to find the shortest path between two vertices in a BGL graph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

So I'm currently working on a project of a word ladder problem and I have already built the graph for storing all dictionary words in it and added the edges in it, I did this using boost graph library.

But what is confusing me is that `breadth_first_search()` function, seems like the parameters only take the starting vertex but no ending vertex.

I checked the documentations and noticed that I can define the BFS visitor for that search function, but since I'm a newbie to the boost library I could not figure out how it works.

Can anybody explain how to implement finding the shortest path between two vertices? I'm using an undirected and unweighted graph.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility> // std::pair
#include "headers.h"
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

using namespace std;

//Define a class that has the data you want to associate to every vertex and 
edge
//struct Vertex{ int foo;}
//  struct Edge{std::string blah;}

struct VertexProperties {
  string name;
  VertexProperties(string name) : name(name) {}
};

//typedef property<edge_weight_t, int> EdgeWeightProperty;
//typedef property<vertex_name_t, string> VertexNameProperty;

//Define the graph using those classes
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
VertexProperties> Graph;
typedef Graph::vertex_iterator Vit;
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor Vde;
typedef Graph::edge_descriptor E;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::adjacency_iterator adjacency_it;


struct my_visitor : boost::default_dijkstra_visitor {
 using base = boost::default_dijkstra_visitor;
 struct done{};

my_visitor(Vde vd, size_t& visited) : destination(vd), visited(visited) {}

void finish_vertex(Vde v, Graph const& g) {
++visited;

if (v == destination)
  throw done{};

base::finish_vertex(v, g);
}

private:
Vde destination;
size_t &visited;
};

//Some typedefs for simplicity
//typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
//typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;
int main()
{
ifstream dictionary("dictionary.txt");
string word;
Graph allWords;
//Vit begin,end;

if(dictionary.is_open())
{
  while(getline(dictionary,word))
    {
  word.pop_back();
      add_vertex(VertexProperties(word),allWords);
    }
 }
else 
cout<<"File openning failed."<<endl;

dictionary.close();
//cout<<num_vertices(allWords)<<endl;
Vit begin,end;
boost::tie(begin, end) = vertices(allWords);

vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> vindex(begin, end);

int first=0;
int second=0;
for(Vit it=begin;it!=end;it++)
{
  for(Vit that=it;that!=end;that++)
    {
      if(isEditDistanceOne(allWords[*it].name,allWords[*that].name))
        add_edge(vindex[first],vindex[second],allWords);
      second++;
    }
  first++;
  second=first;
  cout<<first<<endl;
 }
//Vit temp=begin;
//temp++;   
//cout<<allWords[*begin].name<<"////////////////"<<endl;
adjacency_it neighbour, neighbour_end;
for (tie(neighbour, neighbour_end) = adjacent_vertices(*begin, allWords); 
    neighbour != neighbour_end; ++neighbour)
cout<<allWords[*neighbour].name<<endl;



string firstWord;
string secondWord;

int firstIndex=-1;
int secondIndex=-1;

cout<<"Enter first word:"<<endl;
cin>>firstWord;

cout<<"Enter second word:"<<endl;
cin>>secondWord;


Vit a=begin;
for(int i=0;i<num_vertices(allWords);i++)
{
  if(allWords[*a].name==firstWord)
    {
      firstIndex=i;
      break;
    }
  a++;
}

Vit b=begin;
for(int i=0;i<num_vertices(allWords);i++)
{
  if(allWords[*b].name==secondWord)
    {
      secondIndex=i;
      break;
    }
  b++;
}

if(firstIndex==-1)
  cout<<"First word not in graph."<<endl;

else if(secondIndex==-1)
  cout<<"Second word not in graph."<<endl;

else
{
  Vde start_vertex=vindex[firstIndex];
  Vde end_vertex=vindex[secondIndex];

  size_t visited;
  std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(allWords), 
  boost::default_color_type{});
  std::vector<Vde>                         _pred(num_vertices(allWords),   
  allWords.null_vertex());
  std::vector<size_t>                    _dist(num_vertices(allWords),   
  -1ull);

  my_visitor vis { end_vertex, visited };
  auto predmap = _pred.data(); // interior properties: 
  boost::get(boost::vertex_predecessor, g);
  auto distmap = _dist.data(); // interior properties: 
  boost::get(boost::vertex_distance, g);

  try {
  std::cout << "Searching from #" << start_vertex << " to #" << end_vertex 
  << 
  "...\n";
  boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(allWords, start_vertex, 
                   boost::visitor(vis).
                   color_map(colors.data()).
                   distance_map(distmap).
                   predecessor_map(predmap).
                   weight_map(boost::make_constant_property<E>(1ul))
                   );

  std::cout << "No path found\n";
    return 0;
  } catch(my_visitor::done const&) {
  std::cout << "Percentage skipped: " << 
 (100.0*visited/num_vertices(allWords)) << "%\n";
  } 
 }


 //cout<<adjacency_list[*begin]<<"\t";
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How about [A*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)?

Answer (score 6):

Just abort the search when you discover your target.

Here's a working sample

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf29c106d90a7c3a)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

struct my_visitor : boost::default_dijkstra_visitor {
    using base = boost::default_dijkstra_visitor;
    struct done{};

    my_visitor(V vd, size_t& visited) : destination(vd), visited(visited) {}

    void finish_vertex(V v, G const& g) {
        ++visited;

        if (v == destination)
            throw done{};

        base::finish_vertex(v, g);
    }

  private:
    V destination;
    size_t &visited;
};

int main() {
#if 1
    auto seed = 2912287549; // fixed seed for demo
#else
    auto seed = std::random_device{}();
    std::cout << "SEED: " << seed << "\n";
#endif
    std::mt19937 prng { seed };
    G g;
    generate_random_graph(g, 100, 400, prng);
    print_graph(g);

    V start_vertex = prng()%num_vertices(g);
    V end_vertex   = prng()%num_vertices(g);

    size_t visited;
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(g), boost::default_color_type{});
    std::vector<V>                         _pred(num_vertices(g),   g.null_vertex());
    std::vector<size_t>                    _dist(num_vertices(g),   -1ull);

    my_visitor vis { end_vertex, visited };
    auto predmap = _pred.data(); // interior properties: boost::get(boost::vertex_predecessor, g);
    auto distmap = _dist.data(); // interior properties: boost::get(boost::vertex_distance, g);

    try {
        std::cout << "Searching from #" << start_vertex << " to #" << end_vertex << "...\n";
        boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, start_vertex, 
                boost::visitor(vis).
                color_map(colors.data()).
                distance_map(distmap).
                predecessor_map(predmap).
                weight_map(boost::make_constant_property<E>(1ul))
            );

        std::cout << "No path found\n";
        return 0;
    } catch(my_visitor::done const&) {
        std::cout << "Percentage skipped: " << (100.0*visited/num_vertices(g)) << "%\n";
    }

    size_t distance = distmap[end_vertex];
    std::cout << "Distance from #" << start_vertex << " to #" << end_vertex << ": " << distance << "\n";

    if (distance != size_t(-1)) {
        std::deque<V> path;
        for (V current = end_vertex; 
                current != g.null_vertex() 
                && predmap[current] != current 
                && current != start_vertex;) 
        {
            path.push_front(predmap[current]);
            current = predmap[current];
        }

        std::cout << "Path from #" << start_vertex << " to #" << end_vertex << ": ";
        std::copy(path.begin(), path.end(), std::ostream_iterator<V>(std::cout, ", "));
        std::cout << end_vertex << "\n";
    }
}
```

It generates random undirected graphs with 100 vertices and 400 edges.
For the specific demo seed it prints the following output:

```
0 <--> 45 46 15 83 69 32 38 68 37 
1 <--> 29 52 99 85 10 19 30 78 
2 <--> 42 7 35 80 25 9 23 23 
3 <--> 29 9 15 77 7 58 42 
4 <--> 75 56 98 24 14 40 97 34 84 37 80 30 62 
5 <--> 58 46 80 71 
6 <--> 89 12 47 88 80 
7 <--> 62 69 2 86 88 74 8 33 13 76 3 9 86 48 
8 <--> 64 26 31 7 94 95 77 
9 <--> 83 53 76 3 43 55 7 2 67 72 
10 <--> 51 16 21 20 1 63 31 
11 <--> 38 50 19 88 16 52 
12 <--> 46 6 85 21 61 39 
13 <--> 95 24 17 51 7 
14 <--> 24 4 43 53 
15 <--> 0 51 70 3 43 34 
16 <--> 72 10 23 99 28 35 22 11 96 99 19 38 39 
17 <--> 84 25 13 54 74 96 28 
18 <--> 90 54 88 78 
19 <--> 63 11 61 20 73 22 1 63 90 75 16 
20 <--> 70 57 79 35 19 10 65 79 45 
21 <--> 49 89 43 50 10 38 12 26 67 
22 <--> 41 49 95 99 25 39 23 16 19 81 
23 <--> 35 16 22 95 2 69 2 
24 <--> 76 85 13 42 14 4 85 88 
25 <--> 98 17 22 72 92 60 2 51 
26 <--> 65 48 62 8 50 86 44 37 21 48 
27 <--> 42 82 
28 <--> 92 46 89 16 50 53 59 17 94 
29 <--> 1 33 3 46 91 96 46 48 
30 <--> 60 96 70 79 1 48 4 
31 <--> 37 66 50 8 59 72 32 87 10 67 
32 <--> 84 77 49 71 0 31 81 75 98 66 
33 <--> 29 83 66 7 69 74 80 79 
34 <--> 90 59 73 61 47 4 75 87 15 
35 <--> 51 23 46 20 16 2 68 
36 <--> 70 
37 <--> 31 41 77 68 70 26 70 4 0 60 
38 <--> 11 65 74 0 21 39 50 94 16 86 
39 <--> 48 88 38 22 12 89 16 
40 <--> 81 92 86 4 55 
41 <--> 22 37 74 64 63 63 79 
42 <--> 27 2 24 84 90 65 67 76 72 93 3 
43 <--> 51 75 21 54 9 65 14 53 44 15 
44 <--> 74 82 26 43 
45 <--> 0 86 70 46 94 89 20 
46 <--> 0 12 28 35 45 96 5 29 29 
47 <--> 96 51 6 82 62 34 88 78 
48 <--> 26 99 39 50 59 78 30 29 7 26 
49 <--> 21 22 52 32 99 61 55 69 66 57 
50 <--> 82 11 31 21 26 65 28 48 38 94 55 
51 <--> 43 35 10 47 15 55 13 55 88 25 69 84 
52 <--> 86 49 66 1 93 55 11 74 90 
53 <--> 89 76 9 76 82 28 77 43 14 
54 <--> 87 43 17 98 59 18 66 
55 <--> 68 76 51 65 51 81 52 9 49 92 50 40 
56 <--> 4 82 95 88 80 
57 <--> 20 87 66 62 49 
58 <--> 5 3 
59 <--> 34 75 71 28 31 48 54 70 96 
60 <--> 81 30 81 87 61 61 25 37 
61 <--> 78 62 97 19 49 34 12 60 60 
62 <--> 7 26 69 87 61 70 92 57 47 90 4 
63 <--> 19 41 41 10 72 19 
64 <--> 8 92 41 95 86 
65 <--> 26 38 50 42 55 43 83 79 20 79 
66 <--> 52 31 33 57 87 54 32 49 
67 <--> 97 42 98 9 31 21 
68 <--> 55 74 96 37 0 98 35 
69 <--> 7 97 62 0 97 33 70 49 75 51 23 
70 <--> 20 83 45 78 15 69 30 37 62 37 59 78 77 36 
71 <--> 83 74 59 32 5 88 
72 <--> 16 74 31 25 85 83 42 63 9 
73 <--> 74 34 87 19 
74 <--> 68 73 41 44 72 71 7 38 17 96 33 82 52 
75 <--> 4 43 59 86 32 34 19 69 85 
76 <--> 24 53 55 53 9 42 7 
77 <--> 32 37 79 53 3 70 96 90 8 
78 <--> 61 70 70 48 1 18 47 
79 <--> 20 77 41 30 98 65 20 33 65 82 
80 <--> 82 81 86 93 56 5 33 2 6 4 
81 <--> 40 60 60 80 91 55 32 22 
82 <--> 80 50 44 56 88 53 47 27 74 79 
83 <--> 9 70 71 0 33 95 72 65 
84 <--> 32 17 42 86 4 51 
85 <--> 24 96 12 87 24 1 72 89 87 75 
86 <--> 52 45 40 7 84 26 75 80 7 64 38 
87 <--> 54 57 73 85 62 60 66 31 85 34 
88 <--> 7 39 82 56 11 6 51 24 18 47 71 
89 <--> 53 21 6 28 99 92 45 85 39 
90 <--> 34 42 96 18 77 19 62 52 
91 <--> 81 29 
92 <--> 28 40 64 62 25 89 55 
93 <--> 52 80 42 
94 <--> 8 45 50 28 38 
95 <--> 22 13 83 56 23 64 8 
96 <--> 85 47 30 68 46 90 74 17 16 77 29 59 
97 <--> 69 67 61 69 4 
98 <--> 25 4 54 79 68 67 32 
99 <--> 22 48 16 89 1 49 16 
Searching from #20 to #27...
Percentage skipped: 91%
Distance from #20 to #27: 3
Path from #20 to #27: 20, 65, 42, 27
```

As you can see, 91% of nodes weren't visited.

### Notes

The docs say to use breadth-first search when the edge weight is constant. I couldn't make that work sadly.

Assuming that algorithmic equivalence is asserted, the paths will still be shortest using the early-out (assuming that the edge weight *is* constant).

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I got another problem here. I have tried your code on my project but when compile it it gives me some errors, looks like some boost functions are just does not match the template, so since I'm using an undirected and unweighted graph, is that the reason? Or maybe I have to compile it under some certain environment? Ps: I'm using linux for compiling it. Thanks.

Comment: @Boooooo in all honesty, this is no way to ask for help. Have you looked at my code? Have you checked whether my version uses undirected graph? Have you checked whether it is unweighted? Have you seen my "Notes" about constant weights? If you are not able to check for these differences, why don't you include your own code, so others can do the checking for you?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've been writing complete examples for you now on [several occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493142/some-questions-about-the-c-boost-graph-library). We cannot help if you can't integrate it into your own code. We can't see invisible problems (I can only guess). I'm not going to [be able to] help with that. Instead I suggest posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that confusion....I was about to go out so I did not post my code. I have posted it now, so the problem is that I uses an undirected and unweighted graph to try to find the shortest path between two words, and the compiler shows some errors look like this:

Comment: /home/b/bowu/boost_1_66_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2550:53: error: forming reference to void
           <Graph, value_type, const_reference, Tag> const_type;
                                                     ^

Comment: /home/b/bowu/boost_1_66_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:613:74: error: no matching function for call to ‘choose_const_pmap(const type&, const boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties>&, boost::vertex_index_t)’
        choose_const_pmap(get_param(params, vertex_index), g, vertex_index),
                                                                          ^

Comment: BTW all the graph creation and vertices/edges adding works fine, I have tested it, the only problems is at the dilkstra path finding algorithm.

Comment: I meant what I said. I've spent too much time already, and you've just made my answer mismatch by altering the question.